# getAge() function is not accurate

Tags: java, kotlin

My `getAge()` function is flawed as I passed in `11/18/1955` - and my age function returns 63 when it should be returning 65:

```
fun getAge(birthday: String?): Int {
    if (birthday == null || birthday.isEmpty()) return 0
    val day = birthday.substring(0, 2).toInt()
    val month = birthday.substring(3, 5).toInt()
    val year = birthday.substring(6, 10).toInt()
    val dob = Calendar.getInstance()
    val today = Calendar.getInstance()
    dob.set(year, month, day)
    var age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    if ( today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < dob.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) ) age--
    return age
}`
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: What month is ```18```? ```11/18/1955```. You should validate the input or the expected format is actually MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Yes you're right, the format Facebook uses is `MM/dd/yyyy`. Swapping day and month fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Java 8's LocalDate? Then I would do it like this:

```
    fun getAge(birthdayString: String?): Int {
        if (birthdayString == null || birthdayString.isEmpty()) return 0

        val day = birthdayString.substring(0, 2).toInt()
        val month = birthdayString.substring(3, 5).toInt()
        val year = birthdayString.substring(6, 10).toInt()

        val birthday = LocalDate.of(year, month, day)
        val today = LocalDate.now()

        val age = java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(today, birthday).toInt()
        return age
    }
```